# How to redirect a URL to Application URL in WildFly

Tags: spring-mvc, wildfly-9

I have deployed spring mvc application on WildFly 9. Application Name is MyApp.war.Now I am getting my application by putting the complete URL(https://MyappDomainName.com/MyApp) like this on the browser

How Can I get complete URL mentioned above when I Put https://MyappDomainName.com this on browser. Kindly help me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Modified the standalone.xml by adding the following.

```
<server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
                <https-listener name="httpsServer" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="MyDomain.com" default-web-module="MyApp.war">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                </host>
                <host name="https-default" alias="MyDomain.com" default-web-module="MyApp.war">
                </host> 
            </server>
```